# Центрирование блоков (кнопок) при разной ширине контента

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит `text-align: center`. Из-за разного контента, визуально правая кнопка "выталкивает" левую. Как можно это изменить? Каким образом сделать, чтобы эти кнопки располагались по центру, т.е. чтобы пространство между ними было ровно по центру экрана?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

задай кнопкам одинаковый width

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через флексбоксы

```css
.buttons {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
/*Не обязательные стили*/
button {
outline:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:10px 30px;
background:none;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<button>Показать еще</button>
<button>Оставить отзыв</button>
</div>
```